# Optimizaiton For Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, lazy-loading

Below is the code I've been using to create a website. I'm in the process of getting it online but I am having trouble accessing it on a mobile device using the mobile network. No problems viewing the website using wi-fi, but on a mobile device the site will crash and none of the links will work.

On some web pages, I have a large number of photographs. Could this issue be solved via lazy loading of the photos on the page? Is there any script in the CSS or Javascript that's making the website difficult to use on a mobile device? Any knowledge about trying to solve this issue would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" charset="utf-8">
    
<body>
    
<style>html{visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;}</style>
    
<title>MORIKOBOSHI・</title>
      
<div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">About This Website</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Bibliography</a></li>
    
            
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; position: inline;">
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Custom Google Search" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;">
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style="padding-left: 5px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 50px; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center;">
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html">    

</form>
</div>    

    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:morikoboshi.com' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
 
</script>


<script>
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
} 

</script>

</ul>    
</nav>
</header>     
               
<div class="setsumei">
    
 <br><br><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">◯◯◯◯</h1>
    <br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;"></p>
    
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Author: ◯◯◯◯</p>
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Photos/Videos Taken：◯◯◯◯/◯◯/◯◯</p>
    
 <br><br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;">    
    
    #
 </p>    
        
</div>
        
<br><br><div class="image">
    
  <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">MORIKOBOSHI© | <a href="#">日本語</a></footer>

</div>
</div>
      
<style>
    
html {visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;}
    
.body{background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;}
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}
    
 .image{text-align: center;}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 20px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
        

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>
```